# How do I add count based on two columns in select with more columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

I want to add a column 'count_I_R' to the below select statement.

```
SELECT g.[Id], 
            g.[FirstName], 
            g.[LastName], 
            g.[Email],
            g.[Count_Invited],
            g.[Count_Registered],
            r.[DateReservation],
            r.[AmountPersons],
            row_number() over(order by g.[Count_Invited], g.[Count_Registered] DESC) AS seqnum
    FROM Users g 
        INNER JOIN Reservation r ON r.[UserId] = g.[Id]
    WHERE r.[EventId] = 21
```

The count must be based on *g.[Count_Invited]* and on *g.[Count_Registered]*.

The result should be something like this:

[image: result]

How do I do this?

Comment: Would you please add the sample data and structure' code too? so that we can easily help you?

Comment: It should be 1,2,3,4. Why 3 is missing in sequence

Comment: I think you're confusing the sequence column with the count column I requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `COUNT` with the `OVER` clause to partition the counting of rows with that same *Count_Invited* and *Count_Registered* values.

```
SELECT g.[Id], 
            g.[FirstName], 
            g.[LastName], 
            g.[Email],
            g.[Count_Invited],
            g.[Count_Registered],
            r.[DateReservation],
            r.[AmountPersons],
            row_number() over(order by g.[Count_Invited], g.[Count_Registered] DESC) AS seqnum,
            count(*) over (partition by g.[Count_Invited], g.[Count_Registered]) as count_I_R
    FROM Users g 
        INNER JOIN Reservation r ON r.[UserId] = g.[Id]
    WHERE r.[EventId] = 21
```

See [Exemple B](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on the Documentation:

Answer (score 0):

You need to use DENSE_RANK to achieve this:

```sql
SELECT g.[Id], 
            g.[FirstName], 
            g.[LastName], 
            g.[Email],
            g.[Count_Invited],
            g.[Count_Registered],
            r.[DateReservation],
            r.[AmountPersons],
            Dense_rank() over(order by g.[Count_Invited], g.[Count_Registered] DESC) AS seqnum
    FROM Users g 
        INNER JOIN Reservation r ON r.[UserId] = g.[Id]
    WHERE r.[EventId] = 21
```

Below is the sample I tried:

```sql
DECLARE @table table(invited int, registered int)

insert into @table VALUES(0,3), (0,1), (0,1), (1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,1),(1,1);

SELECT invited,registered, dense_rank() over(order by invited, registered desc) as seqnum
from @table
```

```
+---------+------------+--------+
| invited | registered | seqnum |
+---------+------------+--------+
|       0 |          3 |      1 |
|       0 |          1 |      2 |
|       0 |          1 |      2 |
|       1 |          2 |      3 |
|       1 |          2 |      3 |
|       1 |          2 |      3 |
|       1 |          2 |      3 |
|       1 |          2 |      3 |
|       1 |          1 |      4 |
|       1 |          1 |      4 |
+---------+------------+--------+
```